# Using Property animation in android

Tags: android

I am trying to learn Property animation in Android, but I can´t get my code to work. The idea is to make two animations happen at the same time. I want an image of a football to rotate and translate at the same time. Unfortunately the app crashes in my emulator. Android studio complains that it cannot execute the "onclick- command" in the xml file. What is wrong here?

First the Xml-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.example.runeasheim.codeplayingpropertyanimationjava.MainActivity"
android:background="#CCCCFF">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/footballround"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Animation"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:onClick="setAnimation"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and here the Java code:

```
    import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
    import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }

    public void setAnimation(View view){
        AnimatorSet rootSetAnim = new AnimatorSet();

        ObjectAnimator rotateBall = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360.0f);
        rotateBall.setDuration(2000);

        AnimatorSet childSetAnim = new AnimatorSet();

        ObjectAnimator translateBall = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translationX, 0f, 300f");
        translateBall.setDuration(2000);

        rootSetAnim.play(rotateBall).before(childSetAnim);
        childSetAnim.play(translateBall);
        rootSetAnim.start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
ObjectAnimator translateBall = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translationX, 0f, 300f");
```

to

```
ObjectAnimator translateBall = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translationX", 0f, 300f);
```

Comment: Thank you! Quite obvious, but so easy to miss :-)